# Nuxt injection not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

What am I doing wrong when injecting a logger to the Nuxt instance?

loglevel.client.js

```
import log from 'loglevel';

log.setLevel(process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug');

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('log', log);
  log.debug('logger set up')
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/loglevel.client.js',
    '~/plugins/api.js',
  ],
```

plugins\api.js

```
if (process.client) {
  console.log('on client console')
  this.$log.error('on client $log')
}
```

browser:

```
api.js?e568:4 on client console
08:22:26.456 api.js?e568:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$log')
    at eval (api.js?e568:5:1)
    at Module../plugins/api.js (app.js:1033:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inject` makes `$log` available elsewhere by attaching it as a property to both the root Vue app and to the Nuxt context.

Plugins are ran before the root Vue app is instantiated— you can't access `$log` via `this.$log`, unless `this` refers to the root Vue app instance (like it does in components).

Instead you'll have to access `$log` via the Nuxt context, which is conveniently available as the first argument to your `api.js` plugin.

```
export default ({ $log }) => {
  if (process.client) {
    console.log('on client console')
    $log.error('on client $log')
  }
}
```

From the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/):

> The *(Nuxt)* context provides additional objects/params from Nuxt to Vue
> components and is available in special nuxt lifecycle areas like
> asyncData , fetch , plugins , middleware and nuxtServerInit.

Also, it looks like `loglevel` is registered as a client-side plugin (`loglevel.client.js`). That code will not run server side— so you don't have to wrap anything within `process.client`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.

Comment: I wrapped it with process.client to test this condition. But it fails with "api.js?e568:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined".

Comment: "process" is a node (ie. server-side) global, not a browser global. There's no such thing as "process.client" on the client side, so you will indeed see this error. Just remove it, you don't need to check you're on the client because you specified api is a client-side only plugin by adding ".client.js" to the filename.

Comment: Well, process.client comes from an official Nuxt documentation: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers

Comment: Yup, which is documentation for a universal plugin, not a client-side plugin. Universal plugins run on the server (node), so process.client is recognised by node.